# Equality Comparison assignment

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how this line of code works. Apparently, `isReady` will return `true` if the value for `LAUNCH` is `'ready'` and `false` if not. What is happening here?

```
const LAUNCH = 'ready'

const isReady = LAUNCH === 'ready'
```

Comment: `Launch === 'ready'` is like ***Does Launch Variable is strictly equal to "ready"?*** resulting to `true` that's why when you print isReady it results to true..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the correct answer, the order of evaluation makes all the difference in the world.

The following snippet of code aims to help you better understand how things are evaluated in JS:

```
var obj = {
    true: "stuff"
}

var stuff = function () {
    return function () { 
        return 2+2
    }
}

window[obj["hi".length == 2]]()() == 4 // this weird statement returns true
```

What happens here is this order of evaluation:

1. `"hi".length` is evaluated to `2`
2. `2 == 2` is evaluated to `true`
3. `obj[true]`, after `true` is coerced to a string, is evaluated to `"stuff"`
4. `window["stuff"]` is evaluated to an existent function
5. Calling that function returns another function
6. Calling this other function executes `2+2` and returns `4`
7. And, lastly, `4 == 4` is evaluated to `true`

Comment: @david this shouldn't be the accepted answer. It's only a side note.

Comment: Great explanation! This makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @Adelin, felicitari for an awesome side note.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut, hehe :) multumesc

Answer (score 3):

> What is happening here?

Firstly, it's evaluating the right **expression** `LAUNCH === 'ready'` which is `true`.

Then, just assign this value to `isReady` variable. `isReady` variable will hold everytime one `boolean` value.

Comment: There is a useful [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) table that can guide you if you ever encounter stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful!